# How can I display my gif to the right of text? CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a static landing page and I want my gif to be to the right of text. Right now it is below. I tried to follow tutorials and look up examples but I cannot get it to move right.

```css
.animated.gif {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  animation: animate 1s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <section id="desc">
    <h2>Burgers Done Right</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>With high-quality ingredients</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div>
  <img id="animated-gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Iy1WEZpJQ6V5SVO/giphy.gif" alt="cheese burger gif" />
</div>
```

[image: picture of static page with text "Burgers Done Right - With high quality ingredients" and burger gif under it]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on the parent `<div>` of the text and image, to position the text and image side by side.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p>With high-quality ingredients</p>
  <img id="animated-gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Iy1WEZpJQ6V5SVO/giphy.gif" alt="cheese burger gif" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both of them in a same parent `div`.

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="desc">
      <h2>Burgers Done Right</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>With high-quality ingredients</p>
    </section>
    <div>
        <img id="animated-gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Iy1WEZpJQ6V5SVO/giphy.gif" 
        alt="cheese burger gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give style to parent `div` and give it `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row;`.

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;  //make space between both
}
```

OR, you can use `grid` also.

```css
#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;  // it will arrange all items in two columns
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

I will highly recommend you to master these two, `flex` and `grid` as they are very efficient in building website layouts.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it to the right but I cannot move it further right or further down.

Comment: You can give margin to it.

Answer (score 0):

just float your first div :

```
.content {
   float : left;
}
```